# Strip Elements from a String Depending on a Pattern - Regex R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data-manipulation

Need some regex help. Have a dataframe of some college basketball Vegas spreads. Essentially if the string in VegasOpen starts with a number followed by "o" for "over" or "u" for under, then I need the 3rd element. But if the string does not start with the previously mentioned criteria, then I'd like to retrieve the first element.

If the home team is favored, the string starts with the Over/Under of the game (144.5, 139, etc).

If the away team is favored, the amount they are favored by is listed first (rows 3 and 4).

Ideally I would end up with a dataframe with the spreads for VegasOpen from the HOME team's perspective. Taking rows 3 and 4 for example where the away team is favored: the away team's line is -3 and -6 respectively. But from the home team's perspective that should show as positive 3, and positive 6.

Here is my data:

```
home_team_name     away_team_name     VegasOpen          
Syracuse           Brown              144½u-10-10½ -10   
Xavier             Connecticut        139u-10-3 -10     
Northern Illinois  Ball State         -3 -10137u-10     
Pittsburgh         Notre Dame         -6 -10127½u-10   
Boise State        Fresno State       119½u-10-4 -10  
St. Marys (CA)     Yale               132u-10-12½ -10   
Texas Tech         Alabama State      135½u-10-29 -10    
Gonzaga            North Alabama      142½u-10-32 -10    
Baylor             Northwestern State 145½u-10-37 -10   
Texas              Incarnate Word     128½u-10-31 -10    
Southern Illinois  Grambling State    126½u-10-16 -10
```

Desired output:

```
home_team_name     away_team_name     VegasOpen_home   
Syracuse           Brown              -10.5           
Xavier             Connecticut        -3             
Northern Illinois  Ball State          3                 
Pittsburgh         Notre Dame          6                
Boise State        Fresno State       -4                  
St. Marys (CA)     Yale               -12.5            
Texas Tech         Alabama State      -29              
Gonzaga            North Alabama      -32             
Baylor             Northwestern State -37            
Texas              Incarnate Word     -31              
Southern Illinois  Grambling State    -16
```

@Onyambu your code works. But once there is a game inevitably that lists "143o" instead of "143u", it does not work.  Lets say our strings are 143o-15-9½ -10 and 129o-20-13 EV. How can I apply your regex to account for those variations as well?

Comment: `sub('^[^-]+u-[^-]+-([^-]+).*|^(-\\d+).*', '\\1\\2', df$VegasOpen)`

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(df, vegasopen_home = sub('^[^-]+u-[^-]+(-[^- ]+).*|^-(\\d+).*', '\\1\\2', VegasOpen))
      home_team_name     away_team_name        VegasOpen vegasopen_home
1           Syracuse              Brown 144½u-10-10½ -10           -10½
2             Xavier        Connecticut    139u-10-3 -10             -3
3  Northern Illinois         Ball State    -3 -10137u-10              3
4         Pittsburgh         Notre Dame   -6 -10127½u-10              6
5        Boise State       Fresno State   119½u-10-4 -10             -4
6     St. Marys (CA)               Yale  132u-10-12½ -10           -12½
7         Texas Tech      Alabama State  135½u-10-29 -10            -29
8            Gonzaga      North Alabama  142½u-10-32 -10            -32
9             Baylor Northwestern State  145½u-10-37 -10            -37
10             Texas     Incarnate Word  128½u-10-31 -10            -31
11 Southern Illinois    Grambling State  126½u-10-16 -10            -16
```